# setting Y-Axis value of subview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
[selectorView setFrame:CGRectOffset([selectorView frame], 0, -selectorView.frame.size.height)]
```

In the above code I want to change the value of Y-axis for my subview, as it gets visible from the top of screen and hides my header and search bar. I want to set it just beneath to search bar.

How can I do that ?

Before visibility

[image]

After when subview gets visible

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[selectorView setFrame:CGRectMake(<CGFloat x> , <CGFloat y>, <CGFloat width>, <CGFloat height>)];
```

Hope it works for You

Comment: I have set it like this
[selectorView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 70, selectorView.frame.size.width, -selectorView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: to hide it You have different approaches. You can remove the view or just set the property `alpha = 0`: `[self.view setAlpha:0.0];`